# PFC - High Frequency Input Capacitor Formula

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

I do not understand exactly how the below formula has been found. The formula allows to calcul the high frequency input capacitor (Cin) of a PFC boost converter working in CCM :

[image]

I particularly do not understand the factor $$2\pi$$
The formula is coming from here : https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1166.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559aabdf1128

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the impedance of a capacitor?

Comment: I don't get the \$2\pi\$ bit either. What is the source of the picture?

Comment: I added the source :)

Comment: It is SWAG estimation in the impedance calculation considering a sinusoidal excitation despite a full-wave-rectification-like inductor current envelope. It is a starting point for determining the capacitor value and can be further adjusted once installed the board.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! And I have to minimize this high frequency capacitor to not impact the power factor ?In theory, this capacitor allows to have a perfect sinusoidal current, ie without the input ripple inductor current ?

Comment: Yes, the lower this capacitor is the better the PF. But you still need a few uF. Nothing's perfect.

Comment: Thank youuu ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor impedance is 1 / (2 * Pi * Frequency * Capacitance) so that fragment is left over when you transpose it to solve for capacitance, pretty much they are using that formula to size the capacitor based on impedance for a given voltage, current and ripple requirement

Comment: $$Zc = \frac{1}{Cjw}$$ only for sinusoidal waveforms if I did not do mistakes.